# Wordpress: How do I make a login system with users having their own profile and be able to send messages to each other?

Tags: wordpress, login-system

I want to create a website with Wordpress with the following features:

- User can register and login
- Users have own profile (profile picture and short info)
- Users can send messages to each other
- Only registered users can post comments
- Only certain users can write posts
- Admins can manage users (delete/edit/create/give permission to post)

Any pointers or help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Most of that is straight out of the box with Wordpress. Care to expand a little bit and we can perhaps suggest some plugins or ways to extend? For example, are you trying to run a facebook style social site, shopping cart, reddit etc..

To clarify further:

> User can register and login

Out of the box with Wordpress. To hide the fact that the system is running wordpress have a look at the front end logins which integrate directly with the theme you are currently using. Have a look at [Theme My Login](http://www.jfarthing.com/development/theme-my-login/)

> Users have own profile (profile picture and short info)

Again, out of the box. Set "Anyone can register" to true on the Settings page of wp-admin and when a user signs up they'll be asked to fire in profile information (works well with Theme My Login).

> Users can send messages to each other

Have a look at this plugin: [Cartpauj PM](http://wordpress.org/plugins/cartpauj-pm/)

> Only registered users can post comments

Change the "Users must be regisetered and logged in to comment" in Settings->Discussion

> Only certain users can write posts

Change the role of users in the admin panel. This in conjunction with front-end editing will allow users to submit posts depending on their role without even seeing the admin panel

> Admins can manage users (delete/edit/create/give permission to post)

WP-admin functionality again through users.

Comment: You ask for more information in the comments box bellow the Question.

Answer (score 1):

try [BuddyPress](http://buddypress.org/). It's powerful, extensible and will suit your needs nicely.